# MySQL connector Python variables not registering

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I'm currently using the mysql-connector-python package to execute database actions on Flask. It's been working so well until suddenly the variables don't seem to working correctly anymore. My code is here:

```
@bp.route('/addcart', methods=('OPTIONS', 'POST'))
def addcart():
        ...
        userID = session.get("user_id")
        reqDict = request.get_json()
        itemCode = str(reqDict['itemCode'])
        itemAmt = reqDict['itemAmt']

        if userID is not None:
            db = get_db()
            cursor = db.cursor()
            query = ('SELECT %s FROM cartdata WHERE id = %s')

            cursor.execute(query, (itemCode, userID))
            currentNum = cursor.fetchone()[0]

            if currentNum is None:
                stmt = ('UPDATE cartdata SET %s = 1 WHERE id = %s')
                cursor.execute(stmt, (itemCode, userID))
            else:
                currentNum = int(currentNum) + int(itemAmt)
                stmt = ('UPDATE cartdata SET %s = %s WHERE id = %s')
                cursor.execute(stmt, (itemCode, currentNum, userID))
            ....
```

For some reason, I seem to having trouble with the itemCode variable. When I use it properly, like in the execution of 'query' or 'stmt', it doesn't work. Typically I will get an error saying

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''p1' = 1 WHERE id = 21'".

However, if I do this:

```
query = ('SELECT ' + itemCode + ' FROM cartdata WHERE id = %s')
...
stmt = ('UPDATE cartdata SET '+ itemCode +' = 1 WHERE id = %s')
...
```

It works properly as intended.

EDIT: I've checked my backend, and apparently the UPDATE statement does not actually update anything. So now I'm at a complete loss.

I don't understand why the connector suddenly breaks now for variables. I've checked this variables and its types, but they were the expected types. Any insight would be helpful.

My table schema for 'cartdata' looks something like this:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| p1    | int(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p2    | int(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p3    | int(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p4    | int(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| p5    | int(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: I don't believe the column names in `SELECT x,y,z FROM ...` can be used as variable parameters; they must be hardcoded.

Comment: To provide a *full* answer, it would be nice if you could provide us with the schema of your table.

Comment: I've included the schema. As you can see, the fields are all supposed to be integers, and most are null by default.

Comment: Word of the day: 'Parameterisation'

Comment: @Swift I understand what parameters are, but that shed no light on my problem

Comment: I don't understand why it's not implemented in your code. You should fix that before worrying about bugs, surely? Sorry, I can't help to answer the question, but it was said to me, when I posed a SQL question, and I took the guidance. It was a little more work, sure, but losing one or all of my tables? I didn't mean yo stab, just friendly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when MySQL connector injects your variables into the SQL statement, it formats them according to their type.

You can actually see it in the error message that you get:

```
"p1' = 1 WHERE id = 21'"
  ^
```

So probably, your SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT 'p1' FROM cartdata WHERE id = someId
```

Which is syntactically invalid SQL...

Your second option however seems okay. Btw, it seems weird to adapt the column you want to select depending on the user's input... I'd highly recommend to validate this value with something efficient...

---

### Details

You cannot use `%s` for column names since this injects a **string value** in your SQL query and this results in a non valid SQL syntax (column names are not string values).

As above:

```
SET %s = ...
```

Generates:

```
SET 'colName' = ...
```

which is not valid because you are attempting to affect a value to another value...

That would be the same as trying to do the following in python:

```py
'foo' = 'bar'
```

or

```py
'foo' = 4
```

You can use `%s` when setting values (using `SET colName = %s`) or filtering values (using `WHERE colName = %s`) because the type of the values in the column `colName` is actually a string.

As above:

```
WHERE colName = %s
```

Generates:

```
WHERE colName = 'fooBar'
```

which is valid because you filter on the values that are equal to the string `fooBar`.

---

By the way, you might want to check what

```
SELECT %s FROM cartdata WHERE id = %s
```

gives you as a result. That could result problems... Actually MySQL won't tell you anything, but you result will probably be exactly the value of `itemCode`. (it is valid SQL `SELECT 'hello'`, it just returns `'hello'`).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this works elsewhere when I use %s. For example, I have: ('SELECT id FROM userinfo WHERE username=%s'), which works perfectly, and that variable is also a string type

Comment: I adapted the column selection thing because I wanted to keep track of how many of a particular item (in this case 'p1') each user had. It would've been much easier if I could've just stored a JSON object like in Mongo, but I'm fairly new to MySQL and don't know any other way of doing this

Comment: So my second option doesn't seem to raise any errors, but I've checked my database instance and I realize that it isn't updating 'p1' to 1. p1 is still null for id = 21

Comment: hey, I tried adding more details, hope it helps. feel free to ask for more if not clear enough :)

Comment: This actually explained a lot, thank you! Is there anyway around this then? Because I don't think the second way I'm doing, where I hardcode the 'p1' instead of using a variable, actually executes either. The value of the p1 column is still NULL after the update.

Comment: Stupid question, but when using second option, do you change `cursor.execute(query, (itemCode, userID))` to `cursor.execute(query, (userID,))`?

Comment: Yea I do. If I didn't, I'd get an error saying there were some parameters not used. I've also tried hardcoding the userID too, instead of using the variable for that, but it doesn't work either. I get no errors, but the db doesn't actually update either

Comment: Oh man, I did NOT, what a stupid mistake. That was totally it. Thanks!